# transaction declares authority '{"actor":"mymultisig11","permission":"active"}', but does not have signatures for it under a provided delay of 0 ms

Tags: cleos, transactions, multisig

I am following the given tutorial of multisig :
https://steemit.com/eos/@genereos/eos-multisig-tutorial
And I am stuck for the command

> cleos multisig exec partner11111 payme -p partner11111@active

I have the same name accounts as in the tutorial.
For running this command it gives error:

> Error 3090003: Provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy
>   declared authorizations Ensure that you have the related private keys
>   inside your wallet and your wallet is unlocked. Error Details:
>   transaction declares authority
>   '{"actor":"mymultisig11","permission":"active"}', but does not have
>   signatures for it under a provided delay of 0 ms, provided permissions
>   [{"actor":"eosio.msig","permission":"eosio.code"}], provided keys [],
>   and a delay max limit of 3888000000 ms pending console output:

Wallets are unlocked, keys are imported.
Can anyone please help me with this error.

Comment: your proposal need to be executed by mymultisig11

Comment: I had same error , but took me days before everything works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked, the `eosio.msig` account as privileged was not set. For this, If the system contract is not deployed, we need to deploy it first. Here is a tutorial https://developers.eos.io/welcome/latest/tutorials/bios-boot-sequence/  After following the tutorial, I deploy `eosio.system` contract, set `eosio.msig` account as privileged by `cleos push action eosio setpriv '{"account":"eosio.msig","is_priv":"1"}' -p eosio@active` and then the `exec` command runs successfully.